# Stop Google Talk from signing in

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-desire-hd, google-talk

I recently had to change the password of my primary account. Now Talk keeps trying to sign-in and fails. Having no way of changing the credentials used by talk without completely resetting my phone, I just want to completely disable it (I'm using a better messaging client). Do you thing I could fathom-out how to do this? Anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are still want to use the Google Play Store to grab some apps, are you?

If you disable Talk, the Play Store will not working properly (No auto updating, can't download any app...), so I recommend you use the method below:

Hit:

Setting > Application > Manage Application.

Navigate and click on Google Apps. Then click on “Clear Data” button. Press "OK" on the pop-up dialog. Then find Gmail and Talk under Manage Application, click "Clear Data" as well.

After you've done the above, please head to "Account & Sync Settings" and press your account, then press Menu > Sync Now

Then it should pop up for you to re-enter the password.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This sounds like the solution but I have no Google Apps listed when I go Settings>Applications>ManageApplications>All. Why would that be?

Comment: Hey, don't worry, that's the common difference between versions to versions. You can just try to clear data of Gmail and Gtalk. Or try if you can find GApp (or something similar to Google Apps)

Comment: Cleared data for gmail and Talk; no game, Sign-on Fails with annoying regularity. I know this solution has worked for others maybe just not Android 2.3.5 on HTC Desire. Thanks for the help, going to bite the bullet and just reset the phone. I think Google should be ashamed of the poor quality of that release of Talk.